# SDDM: How to run script as root on login and logout

Tags: kubuntu, autostart, sddm

I'm using Kubuntu 16.10.

What are my options to run a bash-script after login and after logout as root using SDDM?

I already tried switching to lightdm in order to create a /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf file executing my script. However, this results in a boot loop.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `upstart` might do the trick for you.

Comment: You are right, I should probably try that if nothing else works. But isn't it somehow possible to configure systemd to run my script? I have not managed to do that so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sddm` sources `/etc/profile` (common for all users). In case that users's `$SHELL` is `bash` then following files are checked. First file found will be executed:

1. `$HOME/.bash_profile`
2. `$HOME/.bash_login`
3. `$HOME/.profile`

Have a look at `/etc/sddm/Xsession` for more details or for files sourced by different shell. As comment in the file above states:

> Note that the respective logout scripts are not sourced.