# How to run a command as root on login

Tags: 20.04, login, root

I want to run this command as root on login:

```
systemctl mask --now sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

I had some problems with the laptop randomly logging out, every 1 - 2 minutes before I applied this script. (This question is not asking to solve this problem)

I can make a code that allows me to unmask these on demand, and then logout, allowing me to save battery.

I have attempted, as the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887868/sddm-how-to-run-script-as-root-on-login-and-logout) told me to, to have it run via editing the ~/.profile file, but it then showed a black screen after login, and I had to revert that change in recovery mode before it allowed me to login again.

I just naively added the code like this, to the end of the file:

```
~/.profile:
...
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
systemctl mask --now sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

Is there another way I can run this script on login? Or did I do something wrong and how can I do it right?

It is a Samsung Galaxy Book 2, with Windows dual boot, Ubuntu 20.04 with the latest kernel(6.1.9) installed.

Previously, I used Linux Mint on an older Samsung machine, and it ran flawlessly.

Comment: Try with `sudo crontab -e` and edit the command into the crontab file with a line starting with  `@reboot`. See [this link](https://linuxhint.com/cron_jobs_complete_beginners_tutorial/) and other tutorials via the internet if you need more details. Please notice that you may need full path to the commands for example `/usr/bin/systemctl`

Comment: I need one at login, not at boot. There doesn't seem to be a crontab setting for logins

Comment: Sorry, I was not reading the question correctly. At login you can use 'autostart'. In order to avoid having to enter password, you can edit the sudo behaviour: `sudo visudo`. [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353879/lubuntu-20-04-run-a-script-at-login-which-executes-in-a-terminal-window/1354182#1354182) may help you make it work.