# 16.04.2 Nvidia 970M + intel530, can not switch to intel graphics

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I have notebook MSI GS60 6QE with nvidia 970 + intel 530 graphics, last available version of bios at the moment.

I installed Ubuntu gnome 16.04.2 (kernel `4.8.0-52-generic`), with nvidia driver 375 or 378 or 381 (from nvidia ppa) and intel driver 1.4.0 from https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads with ppa added, so, it may autoupdate. `apt-get update` for all.

when i `sudo prime-select intel` a can not even login to the system (in first time something happens in text mode, but i can not figure out what exactly, and than i came back to login screen). if i switch back to `sudo prime-select nvidia` all works good, but laptop is too hot, in case of external graphics.

what i missed? how i can use internal graphics? in the bottom i'll add some lists of relayed commands.

Thank you!

intel driver

```
dpkg -l | grep intel                                     
ii  i965-va-driver:amd64                   1.7.1-0intel1                                 amd64        VAAPI driver for Intel G45 & HD Graphics family
ii  intel-gpu-tools                        1.15-1intel1                                  amd64        tools for debugging the Intel graphics driver
ii  intel-linux-graphics-installer         1.4.0-0intel1                                 amd64        Intel graphics drivers update utility
ii  intel-microcode                        3.20151106.1                                  amd64        Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs
ii  inteltool                              1:20140825-1                                  amd64        Dump Intel CPU / chipset configuration parameters
ii  libcairo-gobject2:amd64                1.15.2-0intel1                                amd64        Cairo 2D vector graphics library (GObject library)
ii  libcairo2:amd64                        1.15.2-0intel1                                amd64        Cairo 2D vector graphics library
ii  libdrm-intel1:amd64                    2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1                        amd64        Userspace interface to intel-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm-intel1:i386                     2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1                        i386         Userspace interface to intel-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libva-drm1:amd64                       1.7.1-0intel1                                 amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- DRM runtime
ii  libva-egl1:amd64                       1.7.1-0intel1                                 amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- EGL runtime
ii  libva-glx1:amd64                       1.7.1-0intel1                                 amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- GLX runtime
ii  libva-tpi1:amd64                       1.7.1-0intel1                                 amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- TPI runtime
ii  libva-wayland1:amd64                   1.7.1-0intel1                                 amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- Wayland runtime
ii  libva-x11-1:amd64                      1.7.1-0intel1                                 amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- X11 runtime
ii  libva1:amd64                           1.7.1-0intel1                                 amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- runtime
ii  va-driver-all:amd64                    1.7.1-0intel1                                 amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API -- driver metapackage
ii  vainfo                                 1.7.1-0intel1                                 amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- info program
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-16.04     2:2.99.917+git20160706-1ubuntu1~16.04.1       amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
```

prime-select (if switch to intel i can not login)

```
prime-select query          
nvidia
```

lspci

lspci -k

```
    00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Skylake Integrated Graphics
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Sunrise Point-H PMC
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Sunrise Point-H SMBus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM204M [GeForce GTX 970M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GM204M [GeForce GTX 970M]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_375_drm, nvidia_375
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Killer N1525 Wireless-AC
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5249 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTS5249 PCI Express Card Reader
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Kernel driver in use: alx
    Kernel modules: alx
3e:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
```

lshw

```
lshw 
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
kvokka-gs60-6qe           
    description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 15GiB
     *-cpu
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 3312MHz
          capacity: 3500MHz
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb intel_pt tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp cpufreq
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 07
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16)
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 07
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:122 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:dc000000-dd0fffff ioport:b0000000(size=301989888)
           *-display
                description: 3D controller
                product: GM204M [GeForce GTX 970M]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
                resources: irq:139 memory:dc000000-dcffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:dd000000-dd07ffff
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:127 memory:db000000-dbffffff memory:70000000-7fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

UPD1: I've tried solution from [NVIDIA-PRIME: Cant switch to intel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879856/nvidia-prime-cant-switch-to-intel) but it odes not helped.

A saw in some post that may be used intel driver `i915_bpo`. can be problem there? Thank you!

UPD2: if i remove nvidia driver, than i'll get freezed system on login screen (in graphics). in console it will be ok. so, defensively the problem is in intel driver.
[image: something wrong with this intel530 graphics, isnt it?]

UPD3: i tried kernel 4.10 + nvidia 381 (with, and with out external intel driver) with same result: system freeze on xServer loading.

Comment: Installing the "Intel driver" was a bad idea.

Comment: try this fix!
https://askubuntu.com/a/923216/680254

Comment: Thank you! It helped. Mostly from https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/764#issuecomment-306543064