# Can't switch GPU to Intel in PRIME Profiles

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

Intel (Power Saving Mode) button is not clickable in NVIDIA X Server Setting in PRIME Profiles. I can switch profile from command prompt following the command `sudo prime-select intel`, but can't do this from GUI. I updated the NVIDIA drivers(tried 455, 460, 470, 510 drivers), and updated Ubuntu from 20.04 to 21.10 and problem hasn't been solved.

Everything worked before and there were no problems with switching.
I tried this way and it doesn't help me [NVIDIA-PRIME: Cant switch to intel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879856/nvidia-prime-cant-switch-to-intel?rq=1)

How can I fix it?

NVIDIA UI Screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGncS.png

Comment: There is a script which does the job to you, I hope it helps: https://github.com/bauca/graphics-switcher